# sending Event attachment to invitees through mail

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had implemented a iphone calendar app with events adding feature..I need to send the event to different invitees through mail with my own custom attachment. When invitees receive the mail if they click on the attachment the same calendar app installed in that system should read the attachment and it should display the event detail.So please suggest me how to do....

Thank you..

Comment: I want to add a custom UTI like .cal  which will be sent to invitees and the .cal is clicked it will open the event in calendar..